# Undefined method `update' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, wicked-gem

I'm trying to get the Wicked Wizard gem working on my Rails app. Once a user registers for the app (using Devise), they're redirected to this form:

**income.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @finance, url: wizard_path, :method => :put do |f|  %>
  <div class="field">
    What <strong>year</strong> were you born?<br>
    <%= f.number_field :age %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    What's your <strong>zip code</strong>?<br>
    <%= f.number_field :zip %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I generated a controller called `finances_welcome_controller.rb` that handles `wizard_path`:

```
class FinancesWelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :income, :expenses
  def show
    @finance = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id] || @finance =     current_user.finances.build(finance_params)
    render_wizard
  end
  def update
    @finance = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id]
    @finance.update(params[:finance])
    render_wizard @finance
  end
```

When I click the `submit` button, I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in FinancesWelcomeController#update
undefined method `update' for #<Array:0x00000104c6ff48>
Extracted source (around line #14):
    def update
        @finance = Finance.find_all_by_user_id current_user[:id]
        **@finance.update(params[:finance])**
        render_wizard @finance
    end
```

Not sure why the update method hasn't been defined since this is the same syntax that my resource's model is using. The Wicked Wizard gem was successfully implemented on [this app](https://github.com/jvenator/wallet/blob/master/app/controllers/renter_profile_steps_controller.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a method starting `find_all_by` will return an array of Active record instances... not just a single one. `update` only works on a single instance.

So, either you want to run through all the instances in the array... using an `each` - or you want to just fetch the first one using `find_by` instead of `find_all_by`

In the case of finding by an id... I'd recommend changing it to `find_by` 
so:

```
@finance = Finance.find_by_user_id current_user[:id]
@finance.update_attributes(params[:finance])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - this seems to have fixed the form submission error, but unfortunately the data is not actually saving. I have my users associated with Finances, and when I hit my _form for editing Finances, the data isn't updated with what was submitted from the wizard.

Comment: @beaconhill - try `update_attributes`. Or ideally `@finance.assign_attributes(params[:finance]); finance.save!` `

Comment: It's saving when I go back to the Wizard page (/finance_welcome/income which has part of the form) but not when I'm on the actual finance edit page (/finance/6/edit)

Comment: You will need to provide further code/information for us to look at then. Is your form calling the update action in your controller>? what params are coming into `params[:finance]` ? is it what you expect? etc